# RTP timestamp not linear?

Tags: rtp

I was trying to reconstruct an audio conversation (a-b call using g711 audio) using the rtp time-stamp. I used to fill silence using difference of two rtp time-stamp and sampling rate. The conversation went out of sync and then I see that rtp time-stamp is not linear.I was not able to get exact clock time using rtp time-stamp and resulted in sync issues. How do i calculate the exact time.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a Stream provided by GStreamer, whic doesnt provide monotonic timestamps.
for Example: The Difference between the stamps should bei exactly 1920, but it is between ~120 and ~3500, but in average 1920.

The problem here is that there is no way to find missing samples, because you never know if the high difference is from the Encoder delay or from a sample missing.

If you have only Audio to decode, I would try to put "valid" PTS values to each sample (in my case basetime+1920, basetime+3840 and so on.)

The big problem here comes when video AND audio were combined. Here this trick doesnt work well, when samples are missing and there is no way to find out when this is the case :(

Answer (score 0):

when you want to send rtp you should notice about two things:
the time stamp is incremented due to the amout of byte sents.
e.g for PT=10, you may have this pattern:
1160 byte , time stamp increment: 1154 and wait 26 ms
lets see how this calculation happens:

## . number of packet should be sent in one second : 1/(26ms) = 38

time stamp increment : clockrate / # = 1154

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to RFC3550 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt)

> The sampling instant MUST be derived from a clock that increments
>   monotonically

Its not a choice nor an option. By the way please read the full description of the timestamp field of the RTP packet, there I found it also:

> As an example, for fixed-rate audio
>         the timestamp clock would likely increment by one for each
>         sampling period.  If an audio application reads blocks covering
>         160 sampling periods from the input device, the timestamp would be
>         increased by 160 for each such block, regardless of whether the
>         block is transmitted in a packet or dropped as silent.

If you want to check linearity then use the RTCP SR RTP and NTP timestamps field. At the SR report the RTP timestamp belongs to the NTP timestamp. 
So the difference of two consecutive RTP timestamp (lets call them dRTPt_1, dRTP_2, ...) and the difference of two consecutive NTP timestamps (lets call them dNTP_1, dNTP_2, ...) and then multiply dRTP_t* with clock rate and check weather you get dNTP_t*.

But first please read the RFC.